# Get the value of a generic declaration programmatically?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I declare a class as follows:

```
public class SomeClass extends AdditionalClass<GenericClass> {
  ...
}
```

This...

```
SomeClass object = new SomeClass();
System.out.println(object.getSuperClass().getSimpleName());
```

...yields "AdditionalClass".  What method call or calls would allow me to interrogate that object and get "GenericClass" as a result?

Comment: Not related to your question but why do you want to inspect the generic type?

Comment: I am programmatically extracting declarations from an application, so that they can be given to non-technical users in a tidy spreadsheet.

Comment: Alright. I just wanted to make sure that you are not taking the wrong path for a simpler task. That said, why would non-technical users care about the generic type?

Comment: That’s raising even more questions. What does a “non-technical user” do with that obviously very technical information?

Comment: @Holger My thoughts exactly in my comment ^^

Comment: Secret sauce, my friends.  _Secret sauce_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to fetch the array of `ParameterizedType`(s) of the superclass. For example:

```
SomeClass object = new SomeClass();
Type parameterizedClassType = 
         ((ParameterizedType) object.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
         .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
System.out.println(parameterizedClassType.getTypeName());
```

This should print `com.whateverpackage.GenericClass`.

Note that even type erasure occurs when `SomeClass` is compiled, the type parameters information about the superclass(es) is preserved, because they are *part* of the definition of the class.

However, if `SomeClass` was a generic one (i.e. was something like `SomeClass<X> extends AdditionalClass<GenericClass>`), then for all the `SomeClass` instances the type-parameter (i.e. `<X>`) would have been replaced with some actual type,  which **would not** have been part of the `.getActualTypeParameters()` array.

Comment: Does this work when `GenericClass` is a generic type itself? i.e. List<String>

Comment: I'm on that ;) It doesn't work if you cast the `parameterizedClassType` to `Class`, though. But as long as you work with the `Type`, everything should be OK.